# Printing custom size of paper using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, printing

I have created a Windows application and connect the button with print function. I can set the paper size, but the problem is that I can't write anything in it.

```
scale_factor = 20 
# Get a handle for the default printer
device_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(device_name)

# Get the default properties for the printer
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
devmode = properties['pDevMode']
devmode.PaperSize=win32con.DMPAPER_B5

# Start printing with the device
hdc = win32gui.CreateDC('Hello ', device_name, devmode)

win32print.StartDoc(hdc,('Hello',None, None, 0))
win32print.StartPage(hdc)
pen = win32gui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor),0)
win32gui.SelectObject(hdc,pen)

win32gui.ExtTextOut(hdc,scale_factor * 72,-1 * scale_factor * 72,1,None,"Testing..")  

win32print.EndPage(hdc)
win32print.EndDoc(hdc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with my code was with the scale factor (-1). Also try to use ExtTextOut() and DrawText(),

Refereance for functions
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__ExtTextOut_meth.html
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__DrawText_meth.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).